# JPA or Hibernate or Spring annotation to specify a query for a relationship?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Can I explicitly specify a query to run to retrieve associated objects, using JPA or Hibernate annotations?

Specifically, I have the following entities:
Tutor,
Student,
and an explicit OneToOne relation between Tutor and Student, Tutorial:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
  @OneToMany Collection<Tutorial> tutorials;
}

@Entity
public class Tutor {
  @OneToMany Collection<Tutorial> tutorials;
}

@Entity
public class Tutorial {
  @OneToOne Tutor tutor;
  @OneToOne Student student;
  // other data
}
```

A Student can be assigned Homework by a Tutor in a Tutorial (but not by a Tutor the student is not assigned to), so:

```
@Entity
public class Homework { 
   @ManyToOne Tutorial tutorial;
   // other data
}
```

Now I want to retrieve all of a Student's Homeworks:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
  @OneToMany Collection<Tutorial> tutorials;

  @OneToMany Collection<Homework> homework;
}
```

But a Homework doesn't have a Student; it has a Tutorial. This is easily expressed in SQL:

```
select a.* 
from Homework a 
join Tutorial b on (a.tutorial_id = b.id)
where b.student_id = ?student.id?
```

Can I express this using JPA or Hibernate or Spring annotations, *directly in the student class, so that it is used when I call Student.getHomework()?*

In other words, what I want is:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
  @OneToMany Collection<Tutorial> tutorials;

  @ExplicitQuery("select Homework where Homework.student = this or something")
  @OneToMany Collection<Homework> homework;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this in Hibernate by using [custom loader](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html_single/#querysql-load)

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(name="customHomeworkLoader", query="select a.* from Homework a join Tutorial b on (a.tutorial_id = b.id) where b.student_id = ?", resultClass = Homework.class)
public class Student {
  @OneToMany Collection<Tutorial> tutorials;

  @Loader(namedQuery = "customHomeworkLoader")
  @OneToMany Collection<Homework> homework;
}
```

The positional parameter (`?`) in named query should be auto replaced by primary key at runtime. I didn't try this code so can't guarantee it'll work, but hopefully it will give you a hint in which way to proceed.